# Database session storage size restrictions

Tags: codeigniter, session, caching

I'm building a web application, I'm considering an approach to integrating facebook with my app where I temporarily cache in the user's session data a json-array of the user's friends' FBIDs when they log into my application. I'm using a database to keep track of my session data.

This is the database table from CodeIgniter that keeps track of user sessions:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(16) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

For those familiar with FQL, I'm thinking about caching there results of this query:

```
SELECT uid, is_app_user FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = xxxxxxxx)
ORDER BY is_app_user DESC
LIMIT 0,1000
```

This returns a list of a users friends and whether or not those friends are users of my facebook application. I have about 770 Facebook friends, and the size of the json-encoded array returned by this query is about 33kb.

I'm using CodeIgniter for my application's back end, and I'm wondering if potentially storing ~33kb worth of data for each session could have any detrimental effect. I plan on letting sessions expire after some reasonable time period to prevent my table from growing forever. Anyone have any insights?

**UPDATE**

Just want to add that the engine driving my session table is MyISAM (not sure if that's best, table-level locking vs. row-level locking for InnoDB... gotta look into that) and the FBID's would naturally be stored as serialized JSON in the user_data (TEXT) column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see this method as being a problem with performance. The problem comes from scalability and the number of concurrent users. Once you session dies, the memory is freed. Therefore, it's a question of how much traffic you're expecting. If you expect a ton of concurrent users, then this could bog your server down (as each user would block out the memory required for their session while they are active).

My question would be what the importance of saving this data in a session rather than a cached file or database table. You can always retrieve the data as it's requested rather than keeping it pent up in a session.

Comment: file caching wouldn't work for my situation as I'm using load-balancing, but caching the list in a database table might also work. I have to look into it a bit more.